# Difference between pidof and pgrep?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I'm not sure why `pidof` doesn’t work, but `pgrep` works.

```
$ pidof squid       
returns nothing

$ pgrep squid
returns 3322
```

How can I get the 3322 using `pidof`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Unix and Linux, it should be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pidof` will return details regarding the name of a actual program whereas `pgrep` will return details regarding any processes that match the provided pattern. This is clearly stated in the man pages of both tools.

```
   pidof [-s] [-c] [-n] [-x] [-m] [-o omitpid[,omitpid..]]  [-o omitpid[,omitpid..]..]  program [program..]
```

vs.

```
   pgrep [options] pattern
```

When you're looking for the executable `squid`, `pgrep` can match it because the pattern matches `/usr/bin/squid*`. Whereas `pidof` cannot find a program called `squid`, because the Squid daemon is likely called something like `/usr/bin/squid-server`.

For example, here I'm looking at the output of `ps` and looking for programs running with the name `systemd` within them:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep systemd
root         1     0  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:05 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
root       425     1  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       480     1  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
dbus       630     1  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root       648     1  0 Sep03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
```

`pgrep` is able to find them as well:

```
$ pgrep -l systemd
1 systemd
425 systemd-journal
480 systemd-udevd
648 systemd-logind
```

But `pidof` only finds the first one:

```
$ pidof systemd
1
```

That's because the PID 1, has the name `/usr/bin/systemd`.